# Implicit Differentiation: Finding points Parallel to y=-x

Tags: implicit-differentiation

The Question asks:

Let $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=2$ be a curve. Find points on the curve where the tangent line is parallel to $y=-x$.

I have got to $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\dfrac{x^{-1/3}}{y^{-1/3}}$ but am confused about how to find the points.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, at any point $P(h,k)$ on $$x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=2$$
the gradient will be $$-\dfrac{h^{-1/3}}{k^{-1/3}}$$ which needs to be $-1$

$\implies h=k$ and we have $$2=h^{2/3}+k^{2/3}=2h^{2/3}\implies h^2=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Any point$(P)$ on $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=a^{2/3}$

can be written as $P(a\cos^3t,a\sin^3t)$

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}=-\dfrac{3\cos^2t\sin t}{3\sin^2t\cos t}=-\cot t$$

We need $-\cot t=-1\implies\dfrac{\sin t}1=\dfrac{\cos t}1=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{\sin^2t+\cos^2t}{1^2+1^2}}=?$

Comment: Sorry, where did the a^(2/3) come from?

Comment: @PeterFerri, Generalized $2$ with $a^{2/3}$